# Orders not being created with recurring profile products

Tags: paypal, payment-methods, recurring

I had a customer sign up for a reccurring profile product and they checked out using Paypal as a payment method.

Magento created a Recurring Payment Profile for her to be charged once a month, but it did not create an order.

For orders placed using our other payment methods a recurring payment profile is created as is an order.

Is there something I need to configure further with Paypal/Magento to have the order and profile created? Has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is old, but in case it helps someone, you need to log in to your PayPal account and set where IPNs (Instant Payment Notifications) should be sent.  I believe it's http://www.yourdomain.com/paypal/ipn. Magento creates the order when it receives an IPN from PayPal.